# Why isn't this writing to my JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea

So I'm trying to read a file into a fileinputstream, then read it byte by byte, converting them to Hexadecimals and outputting them in the JText area. The if = 15 doesn't matter at this point, thats just demonstrating when to new line but I didn't implement it yet. However, for whatever reason nothing will write into the JTextarea when I append it.

```
try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           bin = new int[23123123];
           String[] hexChars = new String[bin.length * 2];
           int hexcount = 0;
           boolean done=false;
           while(!done)
           {
               int next = in.read();
                    if(next == -1)
                    {
                        done=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {   hexChars[hexcount] = Integer.toHexString(next);
                        if (hexcount == 15)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                            textArea.append(hexChars[i]);
                            }
                            hexcount = 0;

                        } else
                                {
                                hexcount++;
                                        }
                        count++;

                    }
           }
                  filelbl.setText("Opened: " + file.getName() + "." );
                in.close();
                out.close();


        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648635/append-a-string-value-from-thread-class-to-jtextarea

Comment: did you try debugging?

Comment: Why are you opening an output stream to the same file you are reading?  This could corrupt your file...

Comment: One thing I see is `try { bin = new int[23123123]; String[] hexChars = new String[bin.length * 2];`. Where's the catch block? This is allocating 200MB+ on the heap, the heap size is typically smaller than this by default. It could be throwing OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Are you calling this in the EDT?

Comment: Ah, I assumed I would need an outputstream at some point. Although removing it I still couldn't get it to run.

Comment: Can you show us your catch block? @wumpz also brings up a good point that if this is long-running, nothing will appear to happen initially. Also verify that your file hasn't been erased after opening the output stream from before. In general, we need to see more of your code. The catch block, how this routine is called (inside an event?), etc...

Answer (score 2):

It's probably just me, but, these...

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
bin = new int[23123123];
String[] hexChars = new String[bin.length * 2];
```

Seem weird to me.  I don't know why you would be opening an `OutputStream` to a `File` which you've just opened an `InputStream` to...The `int` buffer seems overly large and the `hexChars` never need need to exceed `16` characters, not to mention the fact that you are completely ignore the `int` buffer anyway...

Your `try-catch` is a little awkward to.  Generally you should be providing a `finally` block which is used to close any resources, like streams, that you openeded, or your could use the `try-with-resource` feature introduced in Java 7...

```
try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {...
```

Your file reading process also seems a little awkward, for example, the following seems overtly complicated...

```
while (!done) {
    int next = in.read();
    if (next == -1) {
```

And could be reduced to...

```
int next = -1;
while ((next = in.read()) != -1) {...
```

But that's a nit pick ;)

You're not adding any new line characters to the text area nor are you taking into consideration the potential that the `hexchars` may contain a partial result when you finish reading the file.

Since you are reading each `int` from the file one by one, a better solution might be to just convert each `int` to a `hex` value and append it to the `JTextArea` (or maybe a `StringBuilder` depending on your requirements)

For example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class HexViewer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HexViewer();
    }

    public HexViewer() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 16);
                readFile(new File("a file"), ta);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void readFile(File file, JTextArea textArea) {

        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {

            int colCount = 0;
            int next = -1;
            while ((next = in.read()) != -1) {

                textArea.append(Integer.toHexString(next) + " ");
                colCount++;
                if (colCount > 15) {
                    textArea.append("\n");
                    colCount = 0;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

There could be any number of reasons why it's not appearing in your `JTextArea`, you could have forgotten to add it to any visible window or you could be shadowing your variables...

Comment: Hmm....I tried implementing the changes, and adding a static piece of text to ensure text was loading on the jtextarea at all, and it was. but the output isn't showing up still. So I'm not sure what the deal is.I'll have to mess around and try to figure it out

Comment: Unless you can provide an over all runnable example that demonstrates your issue, that's about as far as we can get you

Comment: well, this is my class I've got, and then just a runner main class that sets it to visible.

Comment: edit: god damn I'm dumb. so I just tried it with a docx file and it sent stuff back. so it just doesn't like .txt